# Silverlight 4 Dataform: how to programmatically access auto generated fields?

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I want to enable/disable controls on the status of a checkbox in a DataForm autogenerated form.
So I connected a click event receiver in the AutoGeneratingField event to a the checkbox. 
In the event receiver code I need to access the other fields of the form to enable/disable them, but I did not find a Field or similar collection in DataForm. How can I access the fields?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest if you need to do complex stuff like this that you create the templates inside the dataform. Don't use autogenerated for this.

Comment: I ended up creating forms by hand.